# Pytorch: TypeError 'torch.LongTensor' object is not reversible

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to do a NLP task by pytorch and I used following code to pack my batch of sentences.

```
for iter in range(0, n_iters, batch_size):
    # batch size * max length Variable
    input_batch = input_data[iter:iter + batch_size]
    target_batch = target_data[iter:iter + batch_size]

    # batch size * 1 LongTensor
    input_batch_length = input_length[iter:iter + batch_size]
    target_batch_length = target_length[iter:iter + batch_size]

    # sort batch for pack_packed_sequence
    input_batch_length, input_indices = input_batch_length.sort(0, descending=True)
    input_batch = input_batch[input_indices]

    target_batch_length, target_indices = target_batch_length.sort(0, descending=True)
    target_batch = target_batch[target_indices]

    # TypeError 'torch.LongTensor' object is not reversible 
    packed_input = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(input_batch, input_batch_length, batch_first=True)
    packed_target = nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(target_batch, target_batch_length, batch_first=True)

    loss = train(packed_input, packed_target, input_batch_length, target_batch_length, encoder, decoder,
                 encoder_optimizer, decoder_optimizer, criterion)
```

However, I got an error that 'torch.LongTensor' object is not reversible in the line to pack the batch. Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is the type of `input_batch_length`? Can you provide more details about `input_data`, `input_length`. Btw, it may help you: https://github.com/wasiahmad/universal_sentence_encoder/blob/master/source/nn_layer.py#L75

Comment: @WasiAhmad input_data is a Variable and input_batch_length is a LongTensor. I wrote this referred to an example and they look exactly same.

Comment: The input_batch is a Variable. Can I pack a Variable?

Comment: Yes, Variable can be packed but according to my understanding, the `input_batch_length` should be a list or array.

Answer (score 0):

PackedInput is coded with the expectation a list of longs.

If you want to use a Variable(LongTensor([list])).cuda() for indexes, then you have to bring it back to the cpu, and numpy it, then put it back in.

```
packed_in= pack_padded_sequence(embedded, seqs_len.data.cpu().numpy(), batch_first=True)
    # throw them through your LSTM (remember to give 
    # batch_first=True to the LSTM constructor if you packed with it)
    packed_output, (ht, ct) = lstm(packed_in)
    unpacked_output, _ = pad_packed_sequence(packed_output, batch_first=True)
```

Probly something that could be improved in pytorch.